# Scrollbar with a gap to the right where content can be seen in that gap

Tags: css, scrollbar

Is it possible to create a scrollbar similar to this with CSS?

[image: Scrollbar with a gap]

The important part here being the gap between the scrollbar and the edge, while the content underneath can still be seen in that gap.

Comment: no. as much for the look, width's size and position, color would be in a few browsers

Answer (score 0):

**no**. as much for the look, width's size and position, color would be in a few browsers

for infos if you did not search yet

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-ms-overflow-style